# Control transparency of image texture in nodes?

Tags: texturing, materials, transparency

Here is my problem, i am trying to recreate a handrawn painted texture, and for that i have to mix a crosshatch texture with a watercolour texture using ambient occlusion as the factor in the mix shader. but the crosshatch texture has a white background and looks odd against my watercolour texture.  is there any way i could make my crosshatch texture transparent? i also have a transparent png of the crosshatch if that works better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show an image of your current nodes and the result you are getting?  "Looks odd" is a hard thing to understand.

Comment: how it looks isn't really important to the question. i only want to know how to control transparency in image textures, not looking for material critique. nodes can be added, but it's an incredibly simple node setup, only a mix node with 2 diffuse shaders being fed into it. and with ambient occlusion as the factor of the mix node.

Comment: @Stagbeetle When someone asks for more information, e.g. images, it's because they *do* think that information is important to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it from opaque to alpha blend under the texture box in properties, Then apply any sort of color related node, connect it to a mix shader with a transparent node connected too. Make sure your wire is black and white, if not just change it whith a color ramp. The topmost image texture, I'm pretty sure can be changed to your image beneath it, that way you don't see through the cube. [image]